# How to save html with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to save html code into a database with ajax. My connection information is correct but I can't seem to write to the table.

```
  <div id="others">
  <div id="name"><input type="text" name="results" class="name"></div>
  </div>


$("#button").click(function(){

var results = $('html').html();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "resultsPost.php",
success: function() {
}
}); 
return false;

});
```

Here is the php code

```
    $connect = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $table);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "error";
      exit();
      }


    $results=$_POST['results'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO table(results)VALUES('$results')";

    if (!mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){
      die('error');
    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. The error supression operator is never a good sign either.

Answer (score 3):

You are not sending any data:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "resultsPost.php",
data: results,
success: function() {
}
});
```

I would not recommend doing this though. You are setting yourself up for hell later on...no way to manage data, SQL injections, etc.

Why do you want to save the whole page? I am sure you only need some parts of it. And for those parts you can perform validation. You can even organize your tables in the DB accordingly.

Comment: For some reason it's inserting nothing.


I do only need a part(s) to be saved but thought it was easier to ask the question using the whole page as an example.

Comment: How do you know its inserting nothing? Did you check on the server or on the client/browser? Are there any errors in the Console?

Comment: I checked the database table. They're are rows but no content under the "results" field. I think it might have something to do with the div HTML.

Comment: Do you know how to use the browser console? In Chrome/Firefox press F12 and go to the Console tab on your website... If there are any things in red, can you post those here?

Comment: No reds, only a yellow that says, event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Ok, keep it open and trigger the click event. Any errors in red now?

Comment: I got [12:40:59.417] POST [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 198ms]. I also added an email function to send the variable but the email message came through blank.

Comment: Do the same thing again but go to this view in developer tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#http_headers.  Then see if your data is set in the POST request when you trigger the click event.

Comment: POST 200 OK. It did create a new empty row in the table.

Comment: @Yerpasaur in the Console->Network->Headers do you see your data(your html) being sent? If not then its a JS problem, otherwise its a server side problem

Comment: Status is OK and there is html under Form Data. I guess it's a server problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are sending nothing (no data to the server).

```
var results = $('html').html(); // <- this line should be inside of your ajax request like so

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "resultsPost.php",
data:$('html').html(), //data goes here
success: function() {
}
});
```